# Quotient of standard uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability

Assume $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n$ are IID random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. I am interested in the pdf of the quotient
$$
X = \frac{x_1}{x_1 + x_2 + ... x_n}.
$$
This question is interesting in the context of random portfolios. Here's a little Python script to generate such numbers

```
import numpy as np

def random_weights(n, m=1):
    return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x / x.sum(), axis=1, arr=np.random.rand(n, m))
```

Comment: Where take values the $x_i$?

Comment: It is probably important to mention in your problem statement that the uniform variables take their values in an interval with positive boundaries (at least that is what I think when looking at the computer code, I do not speak Python).

Comment: Yes, sorry. I should have mentioned uniformly distributed in [0,1].

Answer (score 1):

No answer but it might be of some use and is too much for a comment.

I will write $X_{i}$ instead of $x_{i}$.

It is evident that $\left(0,1\right)$ will be serve as support of
$\frac{X_{1}}{X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}}$.

Aiming at its CDF instead of its PDF for $x\in\left[0,1\right]$
we have:

$P\left(\frac{X_{1}}{X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}}\leq x\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}P\left(\frac{X_{1}}{X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}}\leq x\mid X_{2}=x_{2},\dots,X_{n}=x_{n}\right)dx_{2}\dots dx_{n}$

With independence and our knowledge of the distribution we can simplify
the integrand:

$$\text{integrand}=P\left(X_{1}\leq\frac{x\left(x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}\right)}{1-x}\mid X_{2}=x_{2},\dots,X_{n}=x_{n}\right)=P\left(X_{1}\leq\frac{x\left(x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}\right)}{1-x}\right)=\min\left(1,\frac{x\left(x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}\right)}{1-x}\right)$$

After finding its CDF (we are not that far yet) we can find the PDF by differentiating.